# Joke variant of US motto

Tags: translation-check, motto

As a joke, I'm imagining someone being confused about the US motto, and thinking it was "*e unum pluribus*", which hypothetically might mean "out of the one, many" or similar. But I bet that isn't grammatical. So (just as info) what would be grammatical? And could the confused version even sorta, kinda, have the hypothetical meaning?

Comment: [The TV comedy show Community made such a joke.](http://studyroomf.wikia.com/wiki/Greendale_Flag) I'm not sure if this is appropriate as a full answer though :p

Comment: Spoiler alert: I am a German, and the first time I heard that the U.S. motto is "E pluribus unum" was in a Jack Reacher novel about a money counterfeiting operation where $1 bills were "laundered" until they were blank paper, then had $100 printed on them, in an operation called "ex unum pluribus" ("many [dollars] out of one") by the counterfeiters. (On a side note to this side note; to prevent this, every other currency uses bigger notes for higher denominations.)

Answer (score 18):

*E unum pluribus* has just the same meaning as the original (though you might better use the *ex* form of the preposition when it precedes a vowel).

The reverse, 'many out of one', would merely require the cases to be reversed, giving *ex uno plures*.

Answer (score 10):

I like Tom Cotton's suggestion, and I will offer a variant of it.
In the original motto *e pluribus unum* the "one" is neuter.
By analogy, I prefer to make the "many" of the new version neuter:

> *Ex uno plura.*
>   From one, many.

The reason why the translation suggested in the question does not quite work is Latin case inflection.
For example, the preposition *e(x)* requires ablative.

In this neuter reading "many" means "many things" without further specification.
If you want it to refer to "many people", "many peoples", or something in that direction, then Tom's suggestion is better.

Comment: But doesn't the _pluribus_ refer to _hominibus_ or _gentibus_, for either of which _plures_ is correct in the reversed version?

Comment: @TomCotton Good point! I don't know. I just read it simple-mindedly as "from several things one thing" or the other way around. I'll add some discussion of that to my answer.

Comment: I now wonder what is the neuter _unum_ that comes from _pluribus_? This seems to go deeper than I would have believed!|

Comment: I've always taken the _pluribus_ to refer to the various states, and the _unum_ to be the confederation of them (The "United States").  I don't think _unum_ stands for any definite neuter noun, just an abstraction, "one thing/entity".

Comment: This is really making me scratch my head. Words for 'state' are generally feminine, but the most sensible meaning for the original, neuter _unum_ seems to be _imperium_, in which case Joonas's suggestion of _plura_ is the more proper.

Comment: As I understand it, the Founding Fathers looked to the Roman republic for inspiration in creating the new nation, but not to the later Roman empire, so calling the union a _res publica_ would have been congenial to them, but calling it an _imperium_ would not, with its echos of the British empire.  I'll still maintain that one should not look for any understood neuter noun for _unum_ to agree with, but to simply accept it as an abstract, "one thing".

Comment: @varro I think you are quite right. There's not really any option to what you suggest.

Comment: @TomCotton, I believe that the motto is an echo from Saint Augustine's *Confessions* 4.8.13, "ex pluribus unum facere", where the first object of *facere* seems to be *animos* (minds or wills), which applies well to the nation. Or it might be *corda* (hearts), which works just as well. Other neuter possibilities (for the nation, not for Augustine), besides *corda*, might be *foedera* (covenants or pacts) or opera (works, a reference perhaps to the coepta of Virgil in *annuit coeptis*). Or, of course, it could just be "one thing" as varro says.