# Plura or pluria?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, declension, morphology, third-declension

Before answering [this recent question about the US motto](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5872/79), I had to check whether the neuter version of *plures* is *plura* or *pluria*.
I had recalled right: [*plura*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23plura) appears to be indeed the sole form used in classical Latin.
The same corpus search for [*pluria*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23pluria) gave results of grammarians discussing the choice between *plura* and *pluria*.
Some seem to defend the form *pluria*, but I found no attestations of it in a context that does not discuss the very form itself.

So, what's the deal with *pluria*?
Was it a valid alternative spelling, but later all manuscripts were conformed to *plura*?
Is there a good reason to choose *plura* over *pluria*?
Judging by the same corpus, the genitive is exclusively *plurium*, not *plurum*, and this makes me expect *pluria* insead of *plura*.
All this leaves me somewhat confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual form used in Classical Latin seems to have been *plura.* I don't know of any "good reason" to choose *plura* aside from that.

The discrepancy between *plura* and *plurium* was noted by past authors. The main historical source I've seen mentioned<sup>1</sup> that discusses *pluria* is Aulus Gellius, who in *Noctes Atticae* 5.21 recounts an anecdote where a friend of his says *pluria,* is criticized for using this instead of *plura,* and then appeals to historical usage of *pluria* (and *compluria*) and an alleged letter by Sinnius Capito that says *pluria* and not *plura* should be used. An English translation of the passage can be found [here](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Gellius/5*.html).

The critic argues that *plura* should be used based on the rule that comparatives take the ending *-ra* rather than *-ria,* but Gellius's friend disputes that *plus* is a comparative. (From a strictly etymological standpoint, de Vaan 2008 indicates that *plus* did in fact originate as a comparative form.)

1. *[Nox Philologiae](https://books.google.com/books?id=T1JnvNucVBkC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124#v=onepage&q&f=false),*
   by Erik Gunderson, 2009; p. 123-124 and *[Readers and Reading Culture in the High Roman Empire](https://books.google.com/books?id=45eXJSpxdn4C&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131),* by William A. Johnson, 2010, p. 131.