# What would be the correct translation for "Out of few, many"?

Tags: sentence-translation, translation-check, motto

I'm looking for a modification of the famous slogan `E pluribus unum` which translates to `Out of many, one` and is the traditional motto of the United States. Instead I want to say `Out of few, many`. What would be the correct translation for that? 
How about

> E paucis pluria

where

> paucis -> from pucum,pauci -> ablative plural neuter -> few
>   pluria -> from plus, pluris -> accusative plural neuter -> many

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggested translation is good!
The only correction is that I would change *pluria* to *plura*.
(See [this unanswered question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5876/79) for a brief discussion of the two.)
I like your word choices *paucus* and *plus*, so I would go with ***e paucis plura***.

The plural *plures/plura* is a good translation for "many".
The singular *plus* is close to "much".
The Latin and English words don't match exactly, but this rule of thumb should take you to the right direction.

It is worth noting that *plura* is neuter, meaning that the "many" are things.
If you want to refer to many people insted, use *plures*.
The ablative *paucis* looks the same in all genders.
The words *paucus* and *plus* do not seem to refer to any specific nouns in this use, so the distinction is between things and people.
The actual US motto has the neuter *unum*, so *plura* is the most analogous choice.

Another [joke variant of the US motto](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5872/79) was discussed in an earlier question.

Comment: I can't find `plura` in [this declination table](https://www.latin-is-simple.com/de/vocabulary/adjective/6888/). What form should it be? accusative? Also I'm unsure if one needs singulum or plural. I would not even know how to translate the plural of `many` to English so it's hard to say what's needed...

Comment: @mcExchange When it comes to classical Latin, that table is unfortunately wrong. Corpus searches (see the linked question) show that *pluria* is only used when discussing the choice *plura/pluria*, but otherwise it's only *plura*. (There is also a possibility that this is an editorial choice, but my impression is that *plura* is by far more common.) These are two variants of the same form, neuter plural nominative/accusative/vocative. I would translate "many" as the plural *plures/plura*, whereas the singular *plus* is closer to "much".