# How about "From Many, Few"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am looking for the correct way in Latin to say "From many, few". Would this translate to: *e pluribus pauci*?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/what-would-be-the-correct-translation-for-out-of-few-many

Answer (score 5):

Your suggestion *e pluribus pauci* is good.
The best choice depends on what we have few of.
For few people the masculine plural *pauci* is good.
For few things you should use the neuter *pauca* instead.
If you want there to be an implicit noun ("few states/people/cars/foxes/…"), then the choice depends on the gender of that noun.
I'm guessing that you mean few things rather than few people, so I would suggest ***e pluribus pauca*** instead.
The ablative *pluribus* is the same for all genders.